# setParams() not setting values Salesforce Lightning

Tags: salesforce1-app

I created 3 lightning components for App Builder. Used Events are not working in Salesforce1 App. It is working in simulator.

```
        var evt = $A.get("e.InfallibleTech:ContractNumberEvent");
        evt.setParams({ "ContractNo": value});
        evt.fire();
```

setParams() is not working only in Salesforce1 Mobile App. It is working fine in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 simulator.

Comment: I have fixed this issue by giving different variable names. Parent and Child components variable names should be unique.